# Spark SQL Query to assign join date by next closest once

Tags: apache-spark-sql

`CREATE TABLE TABLE_1(
CALL_ID INT,
CALL_DATE DATE);
INSERT INTO TABLE_1(CALL_ID, CALL_DATE)
VALUES (1, '2022-10-22'),
(2, '2022-10-31'),
(3, '2022-11-04');

CREATE TABLE TABLE_2(
PROD_ID INT,
PROD_DATE DATE);
INSERT INTO TABLE_2(PROD_ID, PROD_DATE)
VALUES (1, '2022-10-25'),
(2, '2022-11-17');

CREATE TABLE TABLE_RESULT(
CALL_ID INT,
CALL_DATE DATE,
PROD_ID INT,
PROD_DATE DATE);
INSERT INTO TABLE_RESULT(CALL_ID, CALL_DATE, PROD_ID, PROD_DATE)
VALUES (1, '2022-10-22', 1, '2022-10-25'),
(2, '2022-10-31', NULL, NULL),
(3, '2022-11-04', 2, '2022-11-17');`

Can you help me to create the TABLE_RESULT with a join in a elegant way? This is a very small example.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Thanks anyway.

`SELECT *  FROM (SELECT *, COALESCE(LEAD(CALL_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY CALL_DATE), CURRENT_DATE) AS CALL_DATE_NEXT FROM TABLE_1) AS A LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 AS B ON (A.CALL_DATE<=B.PROD_DATE AND A.CALL_DATE_NEXT>B.PROD_DATE)`